# How to correctly implement an own property getter/setter via Object.defineProperty and utilizing class syntax?

Tags: javascript, class, constructor, getter-setter, defineproperty

it's my code

```
"use strict";

class Employee {
  constructor(firstName, lastName, age, salary, gender) {
    this._firstName = firstName;
    this._lastName = lastName;
    this._age = age;
    this._salary = salary;

    Object.defineProperty(this, "_gender", {
      enumerable: true,
      configurable: true,
      set(value) {
        if(typeof value !== "boolean"){
          throw "Wrong type of data.";
        }else{
          this._newGender = value;
        }
        
      },
      get() {
        return this._newGender;
      }
    });
    this._gender = gender; 


    this._retirementYears = 0;
  }

  retirement() {
    if (this._gender === true) {
      return this._retirementYears = 65 - this._age;
    } else if (this._gender === false) {
      return this._retirementYears = 60 - this._age;
    } else {
      console.error("Invalid gender.");
    }
  }
}

class Teacher extends Employee {
  constructor(firstName, lastName, age, salary, gender, subject, yearsOfExperience) {
    super(firstName, lastName, age, salary, gender);
    this._subject = subject;
    this._yearsOfExperience = yearsOfExperience;
  }
}

const mathTeacher = new Teacher("John", "Smith", 35, 6000, true, "Math", 5);

console.log(mathTeacher);
```

After console.log(mathTeacher) I get two properties relating to gender (_gender and _newGender). I want to get only one property called _gender and I have no idea how to do it. I tried to assign assign value to this._gender but it doesn't work due to "Maximum call stack size exceeded" error

Comment: What does the OP expect from an `Employee`'s own `_gender` property which is implemented via `get`/`set` where the setter does explicitly assign to an additionally introduced own `_newGender` property and the getter always does return the value of the very own `_newGender` property? The entire implementation of `Employee` already is flawed.

Comment: Why are you using a setter at all? Just do the `if(typeof value !== "boolean") throw …;` right in the constructor

Comment: @Delfon ... the OP might have a look into my late provided answer which shows a possible way of implementing the OP's example in a less broken way than the OP's original code does. Despite having received a downvote the OP is encouraged to give it a try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several solution but what made the question interesting, whether cloning of an class instance works for each approach.

To clone an class instance we could use:

```
Object.assign(Object.create(Object.getPrototypeOf(obj)), obj);
```

As turned out only the last approach works with cloning when the property is defined in the prototype. The provided cloning doesn't call the constructor. And calling the constructor is problematic since the arguments are unknown at the time of cloning.

But I would say that we need some `clone()` method in a class to make cloning more flexible. So the cloning failures seen here aren't critical imho.

So let's start it rolling:

You can use a private property (CLONING FAILED !!!):

```js
class Employee {
  #_newGender = false;
  constructor(firstName, lastName, age, salary, gender) {
    this._firstName = firstName;
    this._lastName = lastName;
    this._age = age;
    this._salary = salary;

    Object.defineProperty(this, "_gender", {
      enumerable: true,
      configurable: true,
      set(value) {
        if(typeof value !== "boolean"){
          throw "Wrong type of data.";
        }else{
          this.#_newGender = value;
        }
      },
      get() {
        return this.#_newGender;
      }
    });
    this._gender = gender; 


    this._retirementYears = 0;
  }

  retirement() {
    if (this._gender === true) {
      return this._retirementYears = 65 - this._age;
    } else if (this._gender === false) {
      return this._retirementYears = 60 - this._age;
    } else {
      console.error("Invalid gender.");
    }
  }
}

class Teacher extends Employee {
  constructor(firstName, lastName, age, salary, gender, subject, yearsOfExperience) {
    super(firstName, lastName, age, salary, gender);
    this._subject = subject;
    this._yearsOfExperience = yearsOfExperience;
  }
}

const mathTeacher = new Teacher("John", "Smith", 35, 6000, true, "Math", 5);

try{
  mathTeacher._gender = 'test';
} catch(e){
  console.log(e);
}

console.log(mathTeacher);

const clone = Object.assign(Object.create(Object.getPrototypeOf(mathTeacher)), mathTeacher)
console.log(clone);
try{
  clone._gender = 'test';
} catch(e){
  console.log(e);
}
clone._gender = false;
console.log(mathTeacher, clone);
```

Or make `_newGender` not enumerable (CLONING FAILED !!!):

```js
class Employee {
  
  constructor(firstName, lastName, age, salary, gender) {
    this._firstName = firstName;
    this._lastName = lastName;
    this._age = age;
    this._salary = salary;

    Object.defineProperty(this, "_newGender", {enumerable: false, value: false, writable: true});
    
    Object.defineProperty(this, "_gender", {
      enumerable: true,
      configurable: true,
      set(value) {
        if(typeof value !== "boolean"){
          throw "Wrong type of data.";
        }else{
          this._newGender = value;
        }
        
      },
      get() {
        return this._newGender;
      }
    });
    this._gender = gender; 


    this._retirementYears = 0;
  }

  retirement() {
    if (this._gender === true) {
      return this._retirementYears = 65 - this._age;
    } else if (this._gender === false) {
      return this._retirementYears = 60 - this._age;
    } else {
      console.error("Invalid gender.");
    }
  }
}

class Teacher extends Employee {
  constructor(firstName, lastName, age, salary, gender, subject, yearsOfExperience) {
    super(firstName, lastName, age, salary, gender);
    this._subject = subject;
    this._yearsOfExperience = yearsOfExperience;
  }
}

const mathTeacher = new Teacher("John", "Smith", 35, 6000, true, "Math", 5);

try{
  mathTeacher._gender = 'test';
} catch(e){
  console.log(e);
}

console.log(mathTeacher);

const clone = Object.assign(Object.create(Object.getPrototypeOf(mathTeacher)), mathTeacher)
console.log(clone);
try{
  clone._gender = 'test';
} catch(e){
  console.log(e);
}
clone._gender = false;
console.log(mathTeacher, clone);
```

Actually you could create some utility for this and keep the real value in its scope
(CLONING FAILED !!!):

```js
const createValidatedProp = (obj, prop, cb, value) => {

    let val = value;
    
    Object.defineProperty(obj, prop, {
      enumerable: true,
      configurable: true,
      set(value) {
        if(!cb(value)){
          throw "Wrong type of data.";
        }else{
          val = value;
        }
        
      },
      get() {
        return val;
      }
      
    });
  
};

class Employee {
  
  constructor(firstName, lastName, age, salary, gender) {
    this._firstName = firstName;
    this._lastName = lastName;
    this._age = age;
    this._salary = salary;
    createValidatedProp(this, '_gender', val => typeof val === 'boolean', gender);
    this._retirementYears = 0;
  }

  retirement() {
    if (this._gender === true) {
      return this._retirementYears = 65 - this._age;
    } else if (this._gender === false) {
      return this._retirementYears = 60 - this._age;
    } else {
      console.error("Invalid gender.");
    }
  }
}

class Teacher extends Employee {
  constructor(firstName, lastName, age, salary, gender, subject, yearsOfExperience) {
    super(firstName, lastName, age, salary, gender);
    this._subject = subject;
    this._yearsOfExperience = yearsOfExperience;
  }
}

const mathTeacher = new Teacher("John", "Smith", 35, 6000, true, "Math", 5);

try{
  mathTeacher._gender = 'test';
} catch(e){
  console.log(e);
}

console.log(mathTeacher);

const clone = Object.assign(Object.create(Object.getPrototypeOf(mathTeacher)), mathTeacher)
console.log(clone);
try{
  clone._gender = 'test';
} catch(e){
  console.log(e);
}
clone._gender = false;
console.log(mathTeacher, clone);
```

If you want to use the getter/setter in the prototype (like a JS class would do (but the property isn't enumerable)) use a symbol to keep the real value (symbol properties aren't enumerable):

> Symbol is a built-in object whose constructor returns a symbol primitive — also called a Symbol value or just a Symbol — that's guaranteed to be unique. Symbols are often used to add unique property keys to an object that won't collide with keys any other code might add to the object, and which are hidden from any mechanisms other code will typically use to access the object. That enables a form of weak encapsulation, or a weak form of information hiding.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol

(CLONING OK):

```js
const createValidatedProp = (obj, prop, cb) => {

    let name = Symbol(prop);
    
    Object.defineProperty(obj, prop, {
      enumerable: true,
      configurable: true,
      set(value) {
        if(!cb(value)) throw "Wrong type of data.";
        this[name] = value;
      },
      get() {
        return this[name];
      }
    });
  
};

class Employee {
  
  constructor(firstName, lastName, age, salary, gender, test) {
    this._firstName = firstName;
    this._lastName = lastName;
    this._age = age;
    this._salary = salary;
    this._retirementYears = 0;
    this._gender = gender;
    this._subject = test;
  }

  retirement() {
    if (this._gender === true) {
      return this._retirementYears = 65 - this._age;
    } else if (this._gender === false) {
      return this._retirementYears = 60 - this._age;
    } else {
      console.error("Invalid gender.");
    }
  }
}

createValidatedProp(Employee.prototype, '_gender', val => typeof val === 'boolean');
createValidatedProp(Employee.prototype, '_subject', val => typeof val === 'string');
    

class Teacher extends Employee {
  constructor(firstName, lastName, age, salary, gender, subject, yearsOfExperience) {
    super(firstName, lastName, age, salary, gender, subject);
    this._subject = subject;
    this._yearsOfExperience = yearsOfExperience;
  }
}

const mathTeacher = new Teacher("John", "Smith", 35, 6000, true, "Math", 5);

try{
  mathTeacher._gender = 'test';
} catch(e){
  console.log(e);
}

console.log(mathTeacher);

const clone = Object.assign(Object.create(Object.getPrototypeOf(mathTeacher)), mathTeacher)
console.log(clone);
try{
  clone._gender = 'test';
} catch(e){
  console.log(e);
}
clone._gender = false;
console.log(mathTeacher, clone);
```

Comment: Why is there "#_newGender = false"?

Comment: @Delfon just init it with some value, you can leave it `undefined`. i don't like `undefined`, dangerous

Comment: @AlexanderNenashev ... at wich point has the _"cloning"_ aspect been introduced at the original question? And where is the actual answer which points to the OP's design failures?

Comment: @PeterSeliger just interesting aspect of the topic i wanted to investigate, learning JS

Comment: @AlexanderNenashev ... _"just interesting aspect of **the topic i wanted** to investigate"_. But isn't it the most noble task of the answerer to respond to the questioner and to point out a solution to his problem?

Comment: @PeterSeliger suggested 4 options, free to select

Comment: One could argue that your cloning algorithm is simply broken :-) If you want to truly replicate own properties, including non-enumerable ones and getters, you should use `Object.create(Object.getPrototypeOf(obj), Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptors(obj));` instead of `Object.assign(…)`. Of course that won't help with private fields or any closures over the old instance, but if a `class` uses those, it is recommended to provide a `.clone()` method anyway that would then call the constructor internally. Either way, none of this solves the OP's problem, they care about `console.log` not cloning.

Comment: @Bergi you haven't investigated my answer enough probably given its size and your rep here (just kidding, no offence). Each of my solution solves the OP's problem plus I mentioned that `.clone()` is a better way to support cloning. your proposed cloning is interesting though, but as mentioned the cloning is out of the OP's question's scope, just a by-product

Answer (score -1):

From my above comment ...

> *"What does the OP expect from an `Employee`'s own `_gender` property which is implemented via `get`/`set` where the setter does explicitly assign to an additionally introduced own `_newGender` property and the getter always does return the value of the very own `_newGender` property? The entire implementation of `Employee` already is flawed."*

A possible refactoring ...

- could introduce a single configuration object for each constructor,
- might get rid of the pseudo-private underscore-based prefix-annotation,
- should get the getter/setter implementation for `gender` right,
- is encouraged to correctly implement the calculation for *"years until retirement"*.

```js
class Employee {

  constructor({
    // ensure minimum default values.
    firstName = '',
    lastName = '',
    age = 0,
    salary = 0,
    gender = false,
  }) {
    Object.defineProperty(this, 'gender', {
      set(value) {
        if (typeof value !== 'boolean') {
          throw 'A boolean data type needs to be assigned.';
        } else {
          // assignement to the enclosed/local `gender` variable.
          gender = value;
        }
      },
      get() {
        // return value of the enclosed/local `gender` variable.
        return gender;
      },
      enumerable: true,
    });
    Object.assign(this, {
      firstName, lastName, age, salary, gender,
    });
  }

  // - either rename and correctly implement the `retirement` method
  // - or implement `yearsUntilRetirement` via getter and setter.
  getYearsUntilRetirement() {
    if (this.gender === true) {
      return 65 - this.age;
    } else {
      return 60 - this.age;
    }
  }
}

class Teacher extends Employee {
  constructor({
    // ensure minimum default values.
    subject = '',
    yearsOfExperience = 0,
    // assume additional base configuration.
    ...baseConfig
  }) {
    super(baseConfig);

    Object.assign(this, {
      subject, yearsOfExperience,
    });
  }
}

const mathTeacher = new Teacher({
  firstName: 'John',
  lastName: 'Smith',
  age: 35,
  salary: 6000,
  gender: true,
  subject: 'Math',
  yearsOfExperience: 5,
});

console.log({
  mathTeacher,
});
console.log(
  'mathTeacher.getYearsUntilRetirement() ...',
  mathTeacher.getYearsUntilRetirement(),
);

mathTeacher.gender = false;

console.log({
  mathTeacher,
});
console.log(
  'mathTeacher.getYearsUntilRetirement() ...',
  mathTeacher.getYearsUntilRetirement(),
);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: not different from my 3rd approach when you keep a prop value in a private scope

Comment: @AlexanderNenashev ... Actually the only similarity is the usage of a closure which encapsulates the local variable/state of setting/getting the own `gender` property.

Comment: anyway the same, i've just moved the logic outside in a util function